# ¿cómo Detectar teclas en Segundo plano?

Tags: c#

Por ejemplo quiero que mi programa estando minimizado haga algo al presionar por ejemplo la tecla F9
Así como en ciertos programas para grabar, presiono tal tecla estando fuera del programa y empiexa a grabar

Comment: Debes hacer uso de Keyboard Hooks. Básicamente, "escuchar" los mensajes del sistema operativo y buscar los relacionados con el teclado. [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/604410/579895) tienes una respuesta en inglés que te da un ejemplo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para lograr lo que planteas deberias aplicar el concepto de `Hooking`

Basicamente deberas usar las api de windows para interceptar las acciones de teclado

[A Simple C# Global Low Level Keyboard Hook](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook)

[Processing Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C)

[Keyboard Hooking With C# – Redux](http://refactorsaurusrex.com/keyboard-hooking-with-c-redux/)

Como veras se usa la api

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx
    (int idHook, keyboardHookProc callback, IntPtr hInstance, uint threadId);
```

Pero podria ser mas simple si usas estas libreria

[KeyboardMouseHooks C# Library](http://keyboardmousehooks.codeplex.com/)

[EasyHook](https://easyhook.github.io/)